# Unable to open underlying provider Entity Framework with .mdf file

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, sql-server-ce

I have downloaded the source code from http://www.cainecontrols.com/component/dms/view_document/3 to see how jQuery Full Calander works in ASP.Net.

The attached source code uses Entity Framework and some locally attached **Demo.mdf**

When i run the application from visual studio it says `Underlying provider failed to open`

This is the connection string settings

```
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="ApplicationServices" connectionString="data source=.\SQLEXPRESS;Integrated Security=SSPI;AttachDBFilename=|DataDirectory|\aspnetdb.mdf;User Instance=true" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
    <add name="DemoEntities" connectionString="metadata=res://*/App_Code.EventModel.csdl|res://*/App_Code.EventModel.ssdl|res://*/App_Code.EventModel.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\Demo.mdf;Integrated Security=True;User Instance=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
  </connectionStrings>
```

I have Visual Studio 2012 and SQL Server 2008 Installed in my machine.

Do i need to install any or change a connection string? to make this work